# Kotlin: send on redezvous Channel does not suspend if nobody is reading

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, channel

I don't understand why this program doesn't end:

```
object RedezvousExample {
    @JvmStatic
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        setOptionToShowCoroutineNames()
        runBlocking {
            val ioChannel = Channel<String>()
            val outputFunction: StringDestination = ChannelDestination(ioChannel, this)
            val producerJob = launch(Dispatchers.Default) { producer(outputFunction) }
            val producedValue = ioChannel.receive()
            logMsg("Received $producedValue")
            producerJob.cancel()
        }
    }
}

fun producer(output: StringDestination) {
    for(i in 1..Int.MAX_VALUE) {
        logMsg("Producing $i")
        output("Iteration $i")
    }
}

class ChannelDestination(val output: SendChannel<String>, val coroutineScope: CoroutineScope) : StringDestination {
    override fun invoke(line: String) {
        coroutineScope.async(Dispatchers.Default) {
            logMsg("Sending $line")
            output.send(line)
        }
    }
}

fun logMsg(msg: Any?) = println("${threadName()}$msg")
```

In my (poor) understandig of rendezvous channels, I supposed that the call to output.send would be blocking if nobody was reading the channel, while the producer seems to write continously to the channel even if there are no receive methods pending.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a new coroutine every-time new value is to be sent.

```kotlin
operator fun invoke(line: String) {
    coroutineScope.async(Dispatchers.Default) {
        logMsg("Sending $line")
        output.send(line)
    }
}
```

And this does not suspend, since async is just build launch and forget (but gives a deferred to await on).

Obviously `output.send(line)` line suspends, and releases the thread adding the Continuation (of coroutine inside async block) into paused state and value is not being sent. But still the `logMsg()` is called via the for loop because for loop never suspended.

To overcome the problem your `invoke()` function need to be somehow suspend until the send() call resumes so that for loop will suspend. You may not launch a new coroutine because they does not suspend anyway.

```kotlin
// make producer suspend
suspend fun producer(output: ChannelDestination) {
    for (i in 1..Int.MAX_VALUE) {
        logMsg("Producing $i")
        output("Iteration $i")
    }
}

// make it suspend as well
suspend operator fun invoke(line: String) {
    logMsg("Sending $line")
    output.send(line)
}
```

You've launched the `producer()` function in the `Dispatchers.Default` so all thing will run on it and will suspend till sb receives it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @Animesh was very good. I elaborated it this way:

```
object RedezvousExample01 {
    @JvmStatic
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        setOptionToShowCoroutineNames()
        runBlocking {
            val ioChannel = Channel<String>()
            val outputFunction: StringDestination = ChannelDestination(ioChannel)
            launch { producer(outputFunction) }
            val producedValue = ioChannel.receive()
            ioChannel.close()
            logMsg("Received $producedValue")
        }
    }
}

fun producer(output: StringDestination) {
    try {
        for (i in 1..Int.MAX_VALUE) {
            logMsg("Producing $i")
            output("Iteration $i")
        }
    } catch (e: ClosedSendChannelException) {}
}

class ChannelDestination(val output: SendChannel<String>) : StringDestination {
    override fun invoke(line: String) {
        runBlocking {
            logMsg("Sending $line")
            output.send(line)
        }
    }
}
```

Anyway I had to close the channel in order to end the coroutines, and I'm guessing why the job.cancel() method didn't work.

Comment: `producerJob.cancel()` won't work because there is no suspension point in the function you are calling inside the launch whatsoever. If there is no suspension points you have to do co-operate with the cancellation as mentioned in the docs, you may do a check like `if (!isActive) break` inside the loop to quit it.

Comment: The cancellation is forwarded but the coroutine's continuation never checked for that cancellation notice.

Comment: The documentation of [suspend](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/-send-channel/send.html) is not very clear. It says *Sends the specified element to this channel, suspending the caller while the buffer of this channel is full*  and *This suspending function is cancellable.*, but then states *Note that this function does not check for cancellation when it is not suspended* I'm not sure to understand it...